# How do I put info about messages fetched from the channel to a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

So I want to fetch all embed messages from a specific channel with a tag written in their description.

I started with fetching both embedded and simple messages using `channel.fetchMesssages()` and resolving the promise. I get the collection, I can print messages' values to the console one-by-one but I can't add them to the object to then save them as JSON file.

Here's the code:

```
var news = client.channels.get('id')
var specialMessages = new Object()

news.fetchMessages()
    .then(messages => {
        messages.forEach((m, i) => {
            specialMessages[m.content] = m.id
        })
    })

console.log(specialMessages)
fs.writeFileSync('messages.json', JSON.stringify(specialMessages, null, 2))
```

The thing is I don't seem to add anything to the `specialMessages` because it outputs just `{}` to the console. What's the magic behind it?

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green checkmark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`console.log()` is executed **before** fetching the messages, since the latter operation is asynchronous and not instantly completed (*read about [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)*).

You should place the `console.log(...)` and `fs.writeFileSync(...)` lines immediately after the `forEach()` loop, but within the `.then()` block's [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope).

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
(async () => {
  const news = client.channels.get('id');
  const specialMessages = {};

  const messages = await news.fetchMessages();
  messages.forEach((m, i) => {
     specialMessages[m.content] = m.id;
  });
  console.log(specialMessages);
  fs.writeFileSync('messages.json', JSON.stringify(specialMessages, null, 2));
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

Your specialMessages are {} cause file is not completed. Try console.log after file completed or use callback, async.

```
var news = client.channels.get('id')
var specialMessages = new Object()

news.fetchMessages()
    .then(messages => {
        messages.forEach((m, i) => {
            specialMessages[m.content] = m.id
        })
    })

fs.writeFileSync('messages.json', JSON.stringify(specialMessages, null, 2))
console.log(specialMessages)
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `.map()`.

```js
var news = client.channels.get('id');

news.fetchMessages()
    .then(messages => {
        fs.writeFileSync('messages.json', JSON.stringify(messages.map(m => m.id), null, 2));
    });
```